# IO thread alert GUI thread if error occures

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, client-server, notifications

I have a client/server question that i am trying to figure out the best solution for.

If a client ever gets disconnected from the server, for any reason, i would like a way for the input output thread to alert the gui thread that something went wrong, and thus have the gui thread print an error and gracefully handle it (probably drop back out to the login gui). After the initial gui thread is created, the client could change to any number of guis, depending on what he is doing, so I am thinking i need a way to dynamically see what gui is currently being run.

The way that i was thinking of doing this so far:

1) Create an object that creates and shows every gui. So instead of calling invokeLater...SomeGui.CreateAndShoGui()... we would have this object be responsible for doing that, ie GuiObject.showSomeGui();

2) Have each gui implement an interface, which will insure there is a method that, when called, will gracefully shutdown this gui when we have lost connection to the server.

3) Have a thread that monitors the IO thread and the gui object. If something goes wrong on the IO thread, the IO thread will close down and notify the monitoring thread that we have lost connection the server. The monitoring thread could then alert any open guis (from the gui object) that we have lost connection and that it needs to shut down.

I have just started thinking about this, and so far this is the best solution i have come up with. Does this seem like a reasonable solution that wont add too much complexity to the code? Or can anyone recommend a solution that would be simpler for people reading the code to understand?

Thanks

EDIT:
The other option i am toying with is having an object on the IO thread, that also gets passed to each new gui as it is opened. This object will give the currently opened guis reference back to the io thread, so that the io thread can alert it if something goes wrong. I am leaning against this solution though, because it seems like it would be easier to read if you had one object that was dedicated to get this working (like the above solution), instead of passing some obscure object to each gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just go through each of your ideas:

1) Bad idea - you are tying your whole application together through a single object.  This makes maintainability difficult and is the antithesis of modularity.

2) This is the way to go IMHO.  Since it seems that each gui has unique logic in a failure scenario then it stands to reason that the object that best understands what to do would be the gui object itself.

Another version of this idea would be to create an adapter for each gui to put this failure logic into.  The advantage would be you have one less dependency between your application framework and your gui.  The disadvantage is that this is an extra layer of complexity.  If your gui is already pretty coupled to your application then I would choose the interface method.  If you want to reuse your guis in another application then the adapter way could help facilitate that.

3) This complements #2 nicely.  So let me get this straight - you would have 3 threads: the IO thread, the monitor thread, and the UI thread.  I don't know if you need the monitor thread.  From what you were saying the IO thread would be able to detect a connection problem by itself (probably because some form of IOException was caught).  When a connection problem is discovered the IO thread is not busy since it is just going to shut itself down soon so it might as well just have the responsibility of notifying the guis that there was a problem.  The guis should have their interface method called on the UI thread anyways so the IO thread is just calling a bunch of invokeLater() calls (or asyncExec() calls for SWT) and then the IO thread can just shut itself down.

4) (Your Edit) You are basically describing the Visitor pattern.  I do not think this is a good solution because the call is from the IO thread to the gui and not the other way around.  I am not sure how passing a visitor object around will help in this case.

One final thought.  If you make your interface generic (not gui specific) then you can apply this pattern to other resources.  For instance you may want to flush your user credentials when you lose connection (since you talked about going to the login screen again).  That isn't really gui logic and should not be done from a gui class.

**Edit:** I would use an event model.  Let's say you create a interface like this:

```
public interface ConnectionFailureListener {
    void handleConnectionFailure(); // Add an event object if you need it
}
```

You could then have registration methods in some object (maybe the Runnable for the IO thread or somewhere else that is convenient for you).  These methods would be pretty standard:

```
public void addConnectionFailureListener(ConnectionFailureListener l) {}
public void removeConnectionFailureListener(ConnectionFailureListener l) {}
```

When you show a gui on the screen you would add it to your registration object and when you close the gui you would remove it from the registration object.  You can add other types of objects as needed - for example when you log in you can add a listener for your credential system and remove it again when log out is processed.

This way when you have a failure condition you simply loop through the currently registered listeners and the listener does its thing.

Comment: My next question is, if each gui implemented an interface, how would the IO thread know what to call the closeGui method on? Any number of different guis could be up, and if im not mistaken the IO thread would have to have a reference to the currently gui in order to call that method? Or is there something that i am missing here?